# Downgrade Firebase 9.6 to 9.2.0

Tags: firebase

What commands must I follow on the command line to downgrade. I ran uninstall and reinstalled as well as nom i -S firebase@... but now when I reload the app it just crashes.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about the sequence of events that reproduces the problem, including a description of the problem.  "it just crashes" isn't enough to understand what happened.

Comment: Ok. Essentially I am using expo, and there seems to be a bug with uploadBytes which is the only way I have seen fit after searching through all bug reports and documentation. Apparently it works when you downgrade firebase to 9.2.0. But I manage a consumer tech app at my college and this is not allowing users to post more than one image without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to install an older version of a package, just specify it

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

For example: npm install firebase@9.2.0

You can also add the `--save` flag to that command to add it to your package.json dependencies, or `--save --save-exact` flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json dependencies.

The `install` command is documented here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

npm view firebase versions

And `npm view` can be used for viewing other things about a package too.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

don't forget to remove .lock file first to rebuilt the depedency

can u give the error messege for us....

Comment: how do i delete .lock files?

Comment: remove package-lock.json